# Compile to the actual location of a file

Tags: pdf, python

So I'm really new to Latex and using python to compile a document, using "output\pdflatex test1" However the compiled files are created in the main directory, not the subdirectory of output, where the `.tex` file is. Would love any help on this matter please!

Cheers!

Comment: Change in your script to the output directory and then call `pdflatex test1`.

Comment: As in "cd output"? I did try that but it didn't seem to work unfortunately.

Comment: Imho the python command to switch the directory is `os.chdir`. `cd` is for windows batch files.

Comment: @Ulrike Fischer: `cd` also works for Unix `shell` scripts.

Comment: I've just been using "subproccess.call('cd output')" surely it would have the same effect? I'll test with os.chdir now

Comment: I don't python but "subprocess.call" sounds as if at the end you will be back in the directory you were in when you call this command. @CharlesStaats: Yes, I forget the "e.g.".

Comment: Ahhh yes, I now have it working. Thank you very much for the help!